# Why is 'neither' (without 'nor') singular?

Tags: grammaticality, plural-forms, conjunctions

I ask about 'neither' as a [determiner](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/neither). I want to dredge below [the last 5 paras under 'Tip 2'](https://languagetips.wordpress.com/category/neither-singular-or-plural/) , which don't explain. Neither does p 90, *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* (2005).

Consider: 2. Neither of the parties **?IS?** concerned.
= 3. Both two or more parties **are** ***NOT*** concerned
Does the plurality of the verb in 3, prove that  'neither' should be plural? Why or why not?

I edited the nouns in the original below to simplify.

> You need to be careful, because there are two separate situations.
> *[I omit the second situation here, which I ask NOT about.]*
>
> (1) "Neither" withOUT "nor", as in "Neither of the ... parties
> is concerned with Egypt."
>
> If it is "neither" only, then it is singular and takes a singular verb
> even though the plural verb might sound better to us.

Comment: If, in example 2, [Y] is plural, then the verb is plural.  If [Y] is singular, then the following verb is singular.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: The premise is false.  You can find both singular and plural verbs with *neither* in actual use.

Comment: @snailboat But 'singular agreement is usual' (cp p 90 as above)?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit You might find this graph interesting: https://goo.gl/izCNZf

Answer (score 2):

You aren't talking about the parties together as a unified group, but how they feel individually.  You generally are always doing this when you use *neither*.

This may help you understand:

> Neither [*one*] of the parties is concerned with Egypt

Usually the *one* is understood and left out of the construct.

---

I'm not sure if the below is correct, but here goes:

Let's say you had a total of four parties, and for some reason, they were afflilated in two groups, i.e. party A and B, and party C and D.  Then you could say:

> Neither two of the parties are concerned with Egypt.

You can see how this is confusing unless there's a strong context to help, so I would really avoid using *neither* in this situation, even if it is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure if that second usage is correct either, but it looks wrong. I would say "Neither pair of parties is concerned with Egypt". I don't think you can say neither there, because there are more than two 'two's in a set of four. There are 6 of them. It makes more sense to give the specific groupings of two a name, like the generic 'pair'.

Comment: Might be worth noting that if you replace 'neither' with 'none', you *do* use the plural form.