# "Neither Mary nor John eat (eats?) beef" - singular or plural after 'neither .. nor'?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, correlating-conjunctions, polarity-items

1. Neither Mary nor John **eat** beef.
2. Neither Mary nor John **eats** beef.

Which is grammatically correct?

Comment: Related: **[verb when using neither/nor](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256925/verb-when-using-neither-nor)**

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/neither-michael-nor-albert-is-correct-or-neither-michael-nor-albert-are-corre

Comment: Related question on ELL, [Why is 'neither' (without 'nor') singular?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46171/why-is-neither-without-nor-singular).

Answer (score 1):

You can use both of them. It is not wrong to use either of them. However, **eats** would be a better choice if you have both third party singular nouns or pronoun as in your sentence which means:

> Mary doesn't eat beef, and neither does John.
>   Mary doesn't eat beef and John doesn't eat beef, either.

*Neither X nor Y* is one of the trickiest grammatical points in English. Traditionally, the subject-verb agreement was based on Y, not X and it depended on whether Y was singular or plural, e.g.:

> Neither he nor I **am** right.
>   Neither he nor they **are** coming.

However, if you Google "neither he nor I am", you get 52,600 hits while "neither he nor I are" has 15,800 hits, "neither he nor I is" has 13,500 hits.

Why is this happening? The English language is widely spoken by so many people in the world that the old traditional grammar rules have not been followed by some people and people don't think it is that important to follow them. We sometimes think subject-verb agreement is not that important as long as it makes sense.

Which is grammatically correct between "Neither of them is coming" and "Neither of them are coming"? Both of them are correct. However, the linked [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=neither+of+them+is%2C+neither+of+them+are&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cneither%20of%20them%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneither%20of%20them%20are%3B%2Cc0) favors the former and it is better to use the former.

Comment: In OP's question, I don't think that we can use 'eat' because the subject before the verb is singular. We have to use 'eats' only in the given example.

Comment: @RuchirM The same applies to Neither he nor I, then you think using **am** is the only option?

Comment: Yes. You only wrote it and Google supports it!

Comment: @RuchirM I am not sure how you define the verb **support**, but if you mean it is favored over other two agreements, you are right. But other two are also used and supported by Google.

Comment: Forget Google for a while. If two singular nouns are used in 'neither ...nor' format, it takes a singular verb. If the nouns are *plural* **or** if a noun in **proximity** of the verb is plural, the verb is *plural* @Rathony Said that: neither mine nor your parents ***are*** coming; neither she nor her siblings ***are*** present.

Comment: @MaulikV That's exactly what I explained in the answer.

Comment: I was referring to  your first sentence - *You can use both of them. It is not wrong to use either of them*

Comment: @MaulikV I specifically said it is better to use **eats**.

Comment: It's *not* better, it is *the only choice* if we want to sound grammatical. IMO! :)

Comment: @MaulikV Please show me a reference that says it is the only choice. You mean "Neither he nor I **am**" is the only choice?

Answer (score 1):

> Neither Mary nor John ***eats*** beef.

**is correct.**

**[Reference:](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp)**

> Rule 2. **Two singular subjects** connected by or, either/or, or neither/nor require **a singular verb.**
>
> Examples:
>
> My aunt or my uncle is arriving by train today. 
>   Neither Juan nor Carmen is available.
>   Either Kiana or Casey is helping today with stage decorations.
>
> Rule 3. The verb in an or, either/or, or neither/nor sentence agrees with the noun or pronoun ***closest*** to it.
>
> Examples:
>   Neither the plates nor the serving bowl goes on that shelf.
>   Neither the serving bowl nor the plates go on that shelf.

Comment: Do you mean [FumbleFinger's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/neither-michael-nor-albert-is-correct-or-neither-michael-nor-albert-are-corre/48044#48044) in the link above (second comment) is wrong?

Comment: You are *stuck* between 'you/I' example. That case is **entirely** different. Both are 'singular' **but** take different verbs - You *are*, I *am*. Here, we are *not* talking about the pronouns. @Rathony

Comment: Whether to use pronouns or nouns don't have any influence on determining what agreement we should use. The important thing is the language has changed over the years. I am not trying to say you are wrong. I am just trying to say it has changed.

Comment: So, just one answer from you- *Neither Mary nor John **eat** beef* is correct and *not* wrong. Isn't it? @Rathony

Comment: @Rathony: My ELU answer didn't address the full range of usages - I simply selected *Neither you nor I **is** [whatever we're not]* as an example context where native speakers *don't* slavishly apply the rule ***Neither X nor Y** is always singular* (nearly everyone uses ***are*** there). Nor do we always match the verb form *exactly* to the second element (Y), since that would give us *Neither you nor I **am** Z* (which again is relatively unusual).